# FileStore step by step example with 4.2.1

Tags: atk4

I am wanting to upload a csv file, validate it, and then upload into an existing model.  However, I am using ATK4.2.1 and finding that either the example code that have googled are either missing some steps or not relevant in version 4.2.1.

To this end, for my first step I have tried mixing and matching code in attempt to get a fileStore up and running with no working results thus far.

Is there a step by step tutorial/guide that anyone can point me to.  The reference on the agiletoolkit.org site does not have any examples for the atk4-addons; that I can find.  It seems that it is more involved than just adding an object to the page.

Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245791/how-to-use-atk4-filestore-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

You can find some installation instructions here:

http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/filestore

1. Import this SQL into your database atk4-addons/misc/docs/dbupdates/filestore-001.sql
2. Create a new page, `page_fileadmin extends filestore/Page_FileAdmin`
3. Create directory 'upload' and make it writable.
4. In your model instead of addField use `$this->add('filestore/File');`

If you need images, use `filestore/Image` instead.

Please join https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/agile-toolkit-devel for updates on new documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can't wait to have a play.

Comment: Step 1. OK just had to change type to MyISAM. But have problem with step 2.  I have added location 'filestore' in frontend.php but get 'syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting '{' in /home/tektix/public_html/backend/page/fileManager.php on line 3'.  I think it is the / in 'filestore/Page_FileAdmin.

Comment: Might be files missing from installation as I tried code on above link and it looking for a controller that I cannot find.  attempted_locations: Array ( [0] => /home/tektix/public_html/backend/lib/Controller/Filestore/File.php [1] => /home/tektix/public_html/backend/atk4/lib/Controller/Filestore/File.php [2] => /home/tektix/public_html/backend/atk4-addons/mvc/Controller/Filestore/File.php [3] => /home/tektix/public_html/backend/atk4-addons/misc/lib/Controller/Filestore/File.php [4] => /home/tektix/public_html/backend/atk4-addons/filestore/lib/Page/Controller/Filestore/File.php )